# Diagnosing R package build warning: "LaTeX errors when creating PDF version"

Tags: r, error-handling, package

When building a package, I received the following warning:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
```

I have no idea how to even begin diagnosing this.  Is there a tool that tells me what .Rd file the problem is in?

I get no warnings about any of my Rd files in the checking documentation step....

Comment: I use the `devtools` packages for this. I can't even imagine how hard package building will be without it.

Comment: @Andrie Now that I'm transitioning to dissertating full-time, one of my goals for the next few months is to invest in an optimal workflow.  So I'm switching over to devtools soon, but haven't learnt it yet. :-(

Comment: FWIW, I randomly started getting these errors, and after a couple days of trying to debug latex code and trying all sorts of fixes on the internet, I did a clean install of mactex and all the errors disappeared.

Comment: actually I take that back. It has broken again and getting the same errors. Seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/63), but hadley's solution here works, ie, `R CMD build ./package` `R CMD check ./....tar.gz` from the command line

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try `R CMD Rd2pdf mypackage` to create the manual, and possibly also set the `--no-clean` option to keep the temporary files. This should allow you to debug the LaTeX code triggering the error.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.  Seems the error was due to a missing `inconsolata.sty` file, which I attribute to Ubuntu being horridly behind on its LaTeX updates.  I'm installing TeX Live manually and that will hopefully help me stay up-to-date.

Comment: That is not quite the correct conclusion in my book. `inconsolata.sty` is simply in another texlive fonts package: texlive-fonts-extra. And I seem to have added it the Suggests of the `r-base-dev` package as well.

Comment: Yes, that was not the most logical rant.  When I looked for TexLive to install the package containing inconsolata, I found I didn't have texlive installed in Ubuntu. When I went to install it via the package repository, I realized it was 2+ years out-of-date.  Then I turned into a giant ogre posting silly things across the internets.

Comment: This `R CMD Rd2pdf mypackage --no-clean` worked great for me, too. Also, my problem was solved by installing the recommended fonts for tex-live, a meta-package called `texlive-collection-fontsrecommended`... In case you don't want to play whack-a-mole with missing fonts

Comment: In my case it was a missing `texi2dvi` required to build the document index; I corrected this with `sudo apt-get install texinfo`

Comment: I took me a while to figure out that once you have run  `R CMD Rd2pdf mypackage --no-clean`,  you can inspect the Latex file in `mypackage.Rcheck/mypackage-manual.tex` for errors.

Comment: Thank you @dardisco, that solved it for me too (Linux Mint)

Answer (score 19):

Though @Dirk's answer also helped me to fix the problem I would like to add a bit which might especially help recent updaters. That is, people who haven't encountered other LaTeX / R troubles after the update to 3.1.3 yet. The problem is little bit more general than just building. For me, on OS X the problem was that `R CMD Rd2pdf` as well as the `R CMD CHECK` expected `texi2dvi` to be in `/usr/local/bin` while it was in `/usr/bin`. 
A symlink helped to fix the problem. On terminal type:

```
# to check whether the same issue exists for you
which texi2dvi
# if so
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/texi2dvi
```

Of course if the first line returns something else, you need to adapt the symlink here.

Comment: Thanks! symlink solved the issue for me on OS X with R 3.1.3. In my case it worked with paths in inverted:
ln -s /usr/bin/texi2dvi /usr/local/bin/texi2dvi

Comment: @Johannes yes you're right. It's `ln -s source_file target file`. If you `cd` to the target destination first you only need to pass the source.

Comment: For me on Linux Mint 17.1 (built on Ubuntu 14.04), I needed `texinfo`, not `texi2dvi`. Thanks for the tip and to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652698/texi2dvi-command-not-found) question for teaching me the analog!

Comment: I have: `which texi2dvi` > `/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi`. But I don't know if it is the cause of  `/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi: makeindex failed`, `Error in running tools::texi2pdf()`. Any ideas how can I track the error?

Answer (score 7):

Concluding from the comments and from my own experience the problem often seems to be that some TeX fonts are missing, most often

- `inconsolata.sty` and
- `upquote.sty`

First you have to find the right directory where TeX fonts are stored - in my case this is:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\share\texmf\tex\latex
```

Then you can download them here:

- https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/?lang=en
- https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/upquote?lang=en

Just copy them to the respective folder and in many cases the problem will be solved (in my case too). This should work for all operating systems.

Answer (score 5):

...and another reason is that you **haven't installed** MikTex yet.

1. Download MikTex from [here](https://miktex.org/download) and follow the dialog prompts to install. I found the defaults to be reasonable and worked well for me.
2. Try to build your R package again. It should be OK now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had no error when running `devtools::check()` nor `devtools::document()` but when running `R CMD check mypackage_version.tar.gz` I got an error:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
```

In this question in [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-regarding-manual-from-devtools-check-r-cmd-check/14227) they point to a problem with LATEX installation.
I have the LATEX installation suggested in [R markdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex.html): TinyTex.
I fixed the issue by running in the R console

```
tinytex::latexmk(file = "../mypackage.Rcheck/mypackage-manual.tex")
```

This command automatically updated my LATEX installation so the output file mypackage-manual.pdf was created. After this, I did not get any other error related to PDF when running `R CMD check`:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... OK
* DONE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu just install Tex Live by this command:
`apt-get install texlive` and restart Rstudo if you use it.

Comment: sudo apt install texlive-binaries

Answer (score 0):

First, @dirk-eddelbuettel's [approach in the current question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820135/1082435) identified the missing tex package (which was "makeindex" in my case).

```r
system("R CMD Rd2pdf --no-preview --output=./documentation-peek.pdf ." )

# ... <omitted pages of output> ...
# Warning in sys2(makeindex, shQuote(idxfile)) : '"makeindex"' not found
# Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
#    unable to run 'makeindex' on 'Rd2.idx'
# Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
```

Then @pedro-lima's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69968791/1082435 worked for my specific case.

```r
tinytex::tlmgr_install("makeindex")
```

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes this error occur because of Unicode characters in the package. In this cases, the error message might look like this.

```
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+009D)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

You can find any Unicode characters in your package using `tools::showNonASCIIfile()`. Here's a simple way to check for these characters in your functions and documentation:

```
# functions
functions <- list.files(path = './R', all.files = T, recursive = T, full.names = T)
lapply(X=functions, FUN = tools::showNonASCIIfile)

# documentation
docs <- list.files(path = './man', all.files = T, recursive = T, full.names = T)
lapply(X=docs, FUN = tools::showNonASCIIfile)
```