# Diagnosing R Package build Error: pdfLatex Not Available

Tags: r, packaging, pdflatex

I am trying to build a package in `R`. I made the skeleton, and ran the command `R CMD check package1`. I got an an error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819959/diagnosing-r-package-build-warning-latex-errors-when-creating-pdf-version). 
I followed the solution steps, and the results are:

1. package `devtools` not available for `R 2.15.1`
2. punched in `R CMD Rd2pdf package1`.

> ```
> Hmm.. Looks like a package
> Converting Rd files to LaTeX
> Creating pdf output from LaTeX
> Error in texi2dvi(file=file, pdf=true, clean=clean, quiet=quiet, : pdflatex not available
> Error in running tools::texi2pdf
> ```

3. I looked up [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/setting-up-miktex-and-texworks) amongst other things, installed the complete tex live & MiKTeX. Same error message showed up.
4. I navigated to the directory where pdflatex is located and tried running the command from there. Didn't help.

Is there something I'm missing here, or is there a workaround? Or maybe, Is there a way to suppress pdf generation during package creation?

UPDATE: This error was not thrown when I tried it in LINUX (CentOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have installed MikTeX under Windows, this does not make it available to R. You need to add the location of the latex executables to your PATH environment variable. How to do this exactly depends on your Windows version. For example, [this link](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) describes how to do this for Windows 7. Googling for `change environment variables (windows 7|windows xp|windows 95)` will tell you how to change your environment variables.

Comment: The PATH environment variable has the location of the latex executables. When I installed texlive, it automatically happened. But the error is still there.

Comment: You have installed two Latex distributions, first MikTex and then Texlive?

Comment: I installed MikTex tried it out. Didn't work. I uninstalled it and installed Texlive. didn't work.

Comment: the given link redirects to an irrelevant news website

Answer (score 24):

you certainly can suppress the PDF generation.

```
R CMD check package --no-manual
```

From [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486518-Customizing-Package-Build-Options)

Comment: Excellent thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Download and Install MiKTeX from http://miktex.org/2.9/setup

Step 2: Run

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

in R studio
This command returns the path where Rstudio is trying to find pdflatex.exe
In windows (64-bit) it should return C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
If pdflatex.exe is not located in this location Rstudio gives this error code 41.

Step 3: To set this path variable run:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/",sep=";"))
```

Comment: Thanks, with the last miktex version (20.6.29-) for me this was `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"C:/Users/MY_USER_NAME/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64",sep=";"))`

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this video's instructions to install MikTex on windows:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-xSGZ-RLBU

I also had similar problems about pdfLatex Not Available. After installing MikTex this way, errors like "pandoc.exe: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output. Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 41" can be solved when creating pdf using knitr.

The installation file can be downloaded from:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/protext/ProTeXt-3.1.5-033015.exe

Answer (score 1):

I recently got the same issue. For me, what worked was to install `texlive-fonts-extra`. This works for the Docker R-base image and also for Ubuntu.

In CentOS the package system is different, and you might need to install a higher number of latex-related packages ([example here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/docguide/installlatex.html)).

Comment: This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 and R 4.0.3. I used the following command: `sudo apt install texlive-fonts-extra`

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS I got this to work by running the following in the termina:

```
brew install basictex
```