# Converting into pdf problem 'pdflatex' is not available

Tags: r, pdflatex

My R seems to not recognize existence of latex on my computer. I have identicial problem as in [Diagnosing R Package build Error: pdfLatex Not Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333759/diagnosing-r-package-build-error-pdflatex-not-available)
but I didn't get the point with solution actually, or any other found on internet. The answer which says that I should use `R CMD check package --no-manual` maybe is correct, but I don't know where shut I put that code. To summarize I have the problem following :

```
Converting Rd files to LaTeX 
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  pdflatex is not available
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  pdflatex is not available
```

Can you give me a hand with solving that problem ? Is there any simple solution like simply showing R where can find latex ?

Thanks in advance!