# "texi2dvi" command not found

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, texinfo

Whenever I'm installing a software on my machine it is showing

```
/bin/bash: texi2dvi: command not found
```

My Operating system is Ubuntu 12.04. Do I need install any packages on it.?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to install `texinfo`.

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

Comment: On OpenSUSE: `zypper install texinfo`