# R package RD2PDF error

Tags: r, package

I am having a problem utilizing the [answer presented in this question about diagnosing "LaTeX errors when creating PDF version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819959/diagnosing-r-package-build-warning-latex-errors-when-creating-pdf-version). The solution presented there is to do the following:

> Try `R CMD Rd2pdf mypackage` to create the manual, and possibly also set the `--no-clean` option to keep the temporary files. This should allow you to debug the LaTeX code triggering the error.

Where should I type in that: cmd or R? There is no Rd2pdf in my latex.

Comment: take a look at here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819959/diagnosing-r-package-build-warning-latex-errors-when-creating-pdf-version

Answer (score 4):

The command `R CMD Rd2pdf mypackage` should be executed on the shell command line (Command Prompt if windows, terminal if Mac OS, shell if Linux/Unix) when you are in the directory where the root of your package is.

This command starts `R` and runs a specific set of commands that have been written to do this.