# Diacritics in R documentation via roxygen & Rdpack

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I'm generating documentation using roxygen2 and Rdpack and, when using inline citations, see encoding errors when I build documentation with `R CMD Rd2pdf MyPackage --no-clean` (per [Diagnosing R package build warning: "LaTeX errors when creating PDF version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819959)).

```
! Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textcurrency not provided by
(textcomp)                font family ptm in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead.

See the textcomp package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1523 WÃƒÂ¤
            gele et al. (2009);
```

These appear to arise because non-ASCII characters are being included in `.Rd` files via `\insertCite{}`.  Can I use this mechanism to cite authors whose names include diacritics?

---

Here's a minimal documentation section:

```r
#' Sample function
#'
#' Problematic citation to \insertCite{Wagele2009;textual}{MyPackage}
#'
#' @references
#' \insertAllCited{}
#' @encoding UTF-8
Foo <- function (x) x
```

`inst/REFERENCES.bib` contains (minimally)

```
@article{Wagele2009,
  author = {W{\"a}gele, J W and W{\"a}gele, H},
  year = {2009},
}
```

The `DESCRIPTION` file includes `Encoding: UTF-8`.

Comment: The line 1523 error looks like it contains UTF-8 characters interpreted as Latin1.  (I think the last two chars are the ä; not sure what the first two are.)  So it looks as though there's been some kind of conversion back and forth between Latin1 and UTF-8.  If you look at the .Rd file, does it contain the correct character, or is the error there already?

Comment: The .Rd file contains \insertCite{Wagele2009}.  My suspicion is that Rdpack is replacing this with a Latin1 character at some point in the PDF construction process.

Comment: Right, of course.  I took a look at this.  On my Mac where UTF-8 is native, things are fine.  On Windows I see the problem you had.  I also tried running the `Rdpack::insert_ref` function in R, and it returns the right thing.  So it looks like an R bug, not an Rdpack bug:  R receives a string properly encoded in UTF-8 and treats it as Latin1.  I know the R core group is tired of these issues, and has a test version of R that works entirely in UTF-8, but I haven't tried your issue in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further searching I've found an [answer elsewhere](https://community.rstudio.com/t/40932) that suggests that this is due to Windows' [non-native handling of UTF-8 encoding](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/05/02/utf-8-support-on-windows/), which *[edit] was addressed in R4.0*. <strike>is being addressed in a future release in the R 4.x series.  Unless other readers have further suggestions, it looks like it may have to be a case of "wait a while"...</strike>

Comment: Yes, I just tried the experimental build, and it seemed to work.  If you want to try it, you can get it by following the instructions at https://svn.r-project.org/R-dev-web/trunk/WindowsBuilds/winutf8/ucrt3/howto.html .

Comment: Thanks! It won't get me through CRAN's tests for now, but good to know that I will be able to come back and restore accents once this fix is released.

Comment: I didn't try running R CMD check, I just saw that accents looked fine in a sample help page.  But hopefully CRAN will relax its tests once every platform can run in UTF-8.