# Getting more detailed diagnostic information from rlang after an error with devtools

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I'm trying to develop my first R package. I'm trying to run the

```
devtools::build_manual()
```

function to build a PDF of the documentation. I get an error:

```
Error in `value[[3L]]()`:
! Failed to build manual
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

So then I run this and get

```
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `value[[3L]]()`:
! Failed to build manual
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─devtools::build_manual()
 2.   └─base::tryCatch(...)
 3.     └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 4.       └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5.         └─value[[3L]](cond)
 6.           └─cli::cli_abort("Failed to build manual")
 7.             └─rlang::abort(...)
```

But I don't see how this contains any useful information to what's actually gone wrong. How can I dig deeper into this?

I've tried to run the `devtools::check_man()` function and I get

```
ℹ Updating test_package documentation
ℹ Loading test_package 
ℹ Checking documentation...
plot:
  function(x, ...)
plot.test_package_cv:
  function(model, num, ...)

print:
  function(x, ...)
print.test_package:
  function(model, num, ...)

predict:
  function(object, ...)
predict.test_package:
  function(model, X, ...)
```

I've tried to remove the `plot`, `print`, and `predict` functions but the `build_manual()` function still doesn't work, so I don't think the error lies there.

Comment: `tryCatch()` makes the traces unhelpful unfortunately. {rlang} has `try_fetch()` which fixes this, I wonder why devtools doesn't us it. If you want to debug this you might `debugonce(devtools::build_manual);devtools::build_manual()` and then while debugging, debugonce again whatever is called into the tryCatch, or just just execute it outside of the tryCatch() so it can fail normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I cannot see the current state of your package, I would suggest to run the following commands to make sure that your package is ready to have a manual. Also, please verify that the Roxygen documentation of your functions is well written (see section [17.1 roxygen2 basics](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#roxygen2-basics) of [R Packages (2e)](https://r-pkgs.org) written by Hadley Wickham and Jennifer Bryan).

```
library(devtools)
pkgload::load_all()
styler::style_pkg()
usethis::use_mit_license()
devtools::document()
devtools::check()
devtools::install()
devtools::build_manual()
```

Comment: Not helpful. Much better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820135/880783

Answer (score 0):

sometimes `rlang::last_trace()` can be helpful or when you are sure that the code must work then set `\dontrun{}`, after this the example code won't be evaluated